# NSString into NSArray

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, nsarray

I am currently receiving a file and storing it into an NSString. I am then creating an array out of the string and presenting it in a TableView. This works to a certain extent. I am currently receiving data like this:

CompanyName|AccountCode\r\nCompanyName|AccountCode\r\nCompanyName|AccountCode\r\n and so on...

at the moment i am doing:

```
NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:nil error:nil];
myArray = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
```

which displays data as:

CompanyName|AccountCode
CompanyName|AccountCode
CompanyName|AccountCode

My question is: Can i split the "dataString" into a 2 dimensional array? or should i create 2 arrays (one with the CompanyName, one with AccountCode). And how do i do that?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    if (testArray.count >indexPath.row) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [testArray2 objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [testArray2 objectAtIndex:1];

    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

EDIT:

for test purposes my code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    testArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSString *testString = @"Sam|26,Hannah|22,Adam|30,Carlie|32";
    testArray = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *s in testArray) {

        testArray2 = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
        [dict setObject:[testArray2 objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[testArray2 objectAtIndex:0]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [dict description]);
    NSLog(@"Account code for CompanyName1: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"CompanyName1"]);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    if (testArray.count >indexPath.row) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [testArray2 objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [testArray2 objectAtIndex:1];

    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marzapower is correct, you are probably going to want to use an NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary to store key value pairs. Right below your code above, you could use this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *s in myArray)
{
    NSArray *arr = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    [dict setObject:[arr objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[arr objectAtIndex:0]];
}
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [dict description]);
NSLog(@"Account code for CompanyName1: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"CompanyName1"]);
```

The logging code shows the resulting dictionary as well as how to extract an object based on a company name. Please keep in mind that there is no error checking here, if there is no pipe character in one of the array components the setObject line will blow up.

And of course if you want the account code as the key, just flip around the 1 and 0 in the setObject line.

EDIT: In the cellForRowAtIndexPath you should be accessing the dict dictionary instead of the testArray2 array. For example, you would probably want to do something like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:cell.textLabel.text];
```

(I hope this is right, I do not have a way to immediately test it in Xcode.)

Comment: that works (almost) - the tableview now displays the last CompanyName and AccountCode 4 times (the amount of companies in the string)

Comment: when i run the NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [dict description]); it shows the right data, but get the above problem when showing the data...

Comment: The item for the key needs to be unique to create different entries in the dictionary. If you use the same key repeatedly in the setObject call, it will just replace the value of the one that exists in the dictionary already.

Comment: Actually, that sounds like a problem with your code when you are generating the cell. Can you edit the original question and include your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: how would i specify a different key for an unknown amount of entries?

Comment: I edited my answer to try to help you with your table display issue. Also, I am not sure what you are returning in your numberOfRowsInSection method, but you can always return [[dict allKeys] count] and it will give you exactly enough rows for the dictionary you have.

Comment: yea that works great now! also added the [[dict allKeys] count]; only problem i am having now is that the app crashes when i scroll up or down... any ideas?

Comment: the app crashes as soon as it tries to go into another cell

Answer (score 1):

You can create an associative array, also called "dictionary". With the dictionary you can associate a string (value) to another (key). This way you will obtain something like this:

```
"Company1" => "account code 1",
"Company2" => "account code 2",
...
```

Then you could iterate through its keys with the [`allKeys`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDictionary) method.
Please, refer to the [`NSMutableDictionary`](http://www.google.it/search?aq=0&oq=NSMutabledi&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nsmutabledictionary) documentation for further information.